# static class functions : Instance member cannot be used on type

Tags: swift, function, static

I have had this issue for quite some time now.
I am not able to call a static function with an instance member inside of it.
I get the error :

> Instance member 'matomoTracker' cannot be used on type 'Tracker'

```
class Tracker {

    let matomoTracker:MatomoTracker
    var isAllowed: Bool? //to implement based on UserSessions

    required init(id: String, url: String, isAllowed: Bool) {
        matomoTracker = MatomoTracker(siteId: id, baseURL: URL(string: url)!)
        matomoTracker.isOptedOut = isAllowed
    }

    public func track(category: String, eventDescription: String) {
        matomoTracker.track(eventWithCategory: "category", action: "action", name: nil, number: nil, url: nil)
    }

    static func dispatch() {
        Tracker.matomoTracker.dispatch()
    }

    static func startSession() {
         Tracker.matomoTracker.startNewSession()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Static (type) methods are called on the type, not on a specific instance. What exactly do you expect to happen if you call `Tracker.dispatch()`?

Comment: I know that a static method is called on the type. I am not understanding the error for the the instance member that cannot be called inside a static method. why this error

Comment: is there a workaround or a proper way to proceed

Answer (score 0):

function with prefixed keyword Static or Class can not call instance member. This kind of function can only user static or class member.

here you should use **`static let matomoTracker = MatomoTracker()`**
or if you want to assign matomoTracker later then use

static var matomoTracker:MatomoTracker?

If you want to learn more about static and class then visit below li

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Methods.html